# Getting Error at the time of saving the test cases in Katalon Studio

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, katalon

Getting below error while saving test cases after recording. Can someone help me to understand and how to correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on Katalon [forum](https://forum.katalon.com/t/object-size-issue-cannot-save-entity-file-path-length-limit-exceeded/8742):

You have a file name that is 312 characters long while the max allowed is 255.

1. Check if any objects in the Object Repository has a very long name (this can happen when using e.g. Katalon Recorder and auto-naming).
2. Right-click the object.
3. Change the name to something shorter ("elIssueSummary" in my case, you will have something longer).

[image]

Comment: Do you know where it need to be change

Comment: @Anand Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Will check from my side and let you know my feedback

Comment: The error is not about a file name but a file path